# How to list the packages installed in a target rootfs built using oe-core?

Tags: linux, openembedded

For documentary purpose,
I am looking for efficient ways to list the packages installed in a target rootfs built using oe-core.

Answer (score 2):

The list of packages installed in your image is stored in the manifest file (besides of build history which is already mentioned).

Content of the manifest file looks like:

```
alsa-conf cortexa7hf-neon-vfpv4 1.1.2-r0.1
alsa-conf-base cortexa7hf-neon-vfpv4 1.1.2-r0.1
alsa-lib cortexa7hf-neon-vfpv4 1.1.2-r0.1
alsa-states cortexa7hf-neon-vfpv4 0.2.0-r5.1
alsa-utils-alsactl cortexa7hf-neon-vfpv4 1.1.2-r0.5
alsa-utils-alsamixer cortexa7hf-neon-vfpv4 1.1.2-r0.5
...
```

The list consists of the package name, architecture and a version.

That manifest is located in the deploy directory (i.e. `deploy/images/${MACHINE}/`). Here as an example of the directory listing (there are target images and the manifest file)

```
example-image-genericx86.ext3
example-image-genericx86.manifest
example-image-genericx86.tar.bz2
```

Comment: As the Yocto is similar to the OpenEmbedded project, the information is also valid for it. In addition, if you are using PetaLinux like me, you can also find the manifest file in the `images` directory.

Comment: Well, OpenEmbedded is part of the Yocto project, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46027104/difference-between-yocto-project-and-openembedded for more information.

Answer (score 1):

USER_CLASSES ?= "buildname image-mklibs image-prelink buildhistory"

ERROR: Error executing a python function in /opt/apps_proc/oe-core/meta/recipes-core/eglibc/eglibc_2.17.bb:

The stack trace of python calls that resulted in this exception/failure was:
File: 'buildhistory_emit_pkghistory', lineno: 216, function:

```
    0212:
    0213:        write_pkghistory(pkginfo, d)
    0214:
    0215:
 ***0216:buildhistory_emit_pkghistory(d)
    0217:
```

File: 'buildhistory_emit_pkghistory', lineno: 207, function: buildhistory_emit_pkghistory

```
    0203:        filelist = []
    0204:        pkginfo.size = 0
    0205:        for f in pkgfiles[pkg]:
    0206:            relpth = os.path.relpath(f, pkgdestpkg)
 ***0207:            fstat = os.lstat(f)
    0208:            pkginfo.size += fstat.st_size
    0209:            filelist.append(os.sep + relpth)
    0210:        filelist.sort()
    0211:        pkginfo.filelist = " ".join(filelist)
```

Exception: OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/opt/apps_proc/oe-core/build/tmp-eglibc/work/armv7a-vfp-neon-oe-linux-gnueabi/eglibc/2.17-r3/packages-split/eglibc-thread-db/lib/libthread_db-1.0.so'

ERROR: Function failed: buildhistory_emit_pkghistory

Answer (score 0):

Add build history to your USER_CLASSES variable in local.conf

USER_CLASSES ?= "buildhistory"

After you rerun the build look in build/buildhistory for more info.

You may need to force rebuilds to properly populate the directory.